# Integrable Functions

Tags: functions, convolution, integrable-systems

Let f and g be $2π-periodic$ integrable functions on $\mathbb{R} $ and let $f ∗ g$ denote their
convolution on $[−π, π]$. Prove that
$\widehat{f∗g(n)} = \hat{f}(n)\hat{g}(n)$.

I'm stuck with how to solve this, I don't really know where to begin.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: There is a proof on wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem

Comment: Where to begin: write down, using the definitions, the formula for $\widehat{f*g}(n)$.